# Why js onunload is invoked when popup page opens?

Tags: javascript, firefox, onunload, popupwindow

According to the documentation (I'm only using **Firefox**) :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload

> The unload event is raised when the
>   document is unloaded.

But my code below would trigger the alert even though the child window (i.e. variable name "win") has just been **opened**, not closed.

```
alert("failed but still reload:" + win.isSuccess);

"failed but still reload: undefined"
```

My attention is to invoke that onunload when the child window is closed. What am I doing wrong here??

**Code**

```
function showInsertPopup() {
    var ddId = document.getElementById("workRegionDropdown");
    var index = ddId.selectedIndex;
    var workRegionCode = ddId.options[index].value;
    if(workRegionCode != "") {
          var win = window.open(machineFormPopup + "?typeFlag=1&workRegionCode=" + workRegionCode, "window1", "menubar=no, width=700, height=550, toolbar=no");
          win.onunload = function() {
                if(win.isSuccess) {
                      alert("success reload!")
                      getRecordByWorkRegion();
                }
                else {
                      //here gets print out somehow
                      alert("failed but still reload:" + win.isSuccess);
                      getRecordByWorkRegion();
                }
          }//end inner function onunload
     }
 }//end showInsertPopup()
```

**Child window page has just simple js:**

```
window.isSuccess = 1;
window.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually see the unload for the original `about:blank` document in the popup window first. (You can verify this by looking at the window's location.) You should then see another unload when the popup window closes.

Comment: ah i see, that lame :( why they named it onunload... what if I want to invoke that event only once really when the window closes..

Comment: Web pages don't get to find out why the page is being unloaded.

Comment: @Raj Any given unload listener will only see the unload for the window that it is listening to. (If you're working with iframes rather than windows then I can think you can listen for multiple unloads.)