# onunload event of Pop-Up at IE9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have implemented a web application which runs on IE9. I have a custom code for:

```
<body class="ui-widget-content" onunload="cleanUp()">
```

cleanUp method is necessary for me because of it cleans something which may cause a memory leak issue. Everything is OK at standalone IE) when I click close button of browser (I mean when I click close browser it fires `onunload` event and cleanUp is called).

However our customer runs our web application from their web application within a popup (they also use IE). I see that when they click close button of pop-up that event is not triggered.

Is there any solution that I can handle it within my application (I mean how can I understand that pop-up is closed).

Comment: Both of you use same IE version?

Comment: Yes, exactly same versions.

Comment: See this if can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793282/javascript-jquery-open-window-popup-fires-onunload-after-aboutblank-unloads